# Make dead keys insert both characters if the combination is not recognized

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb, dead-keys

There are ways to configure dead keys in Linux to mimic the behavior they have in Windows ?

This document describe how it works in Windows:[US-Int'l Keyboard Layout to Type Accented Characters](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/97738)

The difference between Linux and Windows dead keys is highlighted in bold:

> When you press the APOSTROPHE (') key, QUOTATION MARK (") key, ACCENT GRAVE (`) key, TILDE (~) key, ACCENT CIRCUMFLEX key, or CARET (^) key, nothing appears on the screen until you press the a second key. If you press one of the letters designated as eligible to receive an accent mark, the accented version of the letter appears. **If you press an ineligible key, two separate characters appear.**

In Linux when you press a second key not eligible to receive a accent, the first key pressed is lost. This reduce the typing productivity, a lot.